# Magento 2 works too slow on local system in development environment

Tags: magento2, php, development

Magento 2 works very slow on local desktop system. This affects development speed. I am using wamp server. Works fine with Magento 1.

Is there anything which can make Magento 2 run faster in my local system?

Or Anyone have suggestions for Magento 2 development on local system?

Comment: check this [http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99155/after-installing-my-magento2-is-extremely-slow-though-i-did-not-install-sample/99268]

Comment: I already know these steps given in your link. But this doesn't affects much.

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.0 is very slow do following step which can increase your magento 2.

1. disable cache
2. compress css,js and images.
3. remove unnecessary module and extension.
4. perform indexing.

Comment: disable cache - really?

Comment: by disabling cache your execution speed is some increase.