# Magento 2 speed issues

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I have migrate Magento 1.7.x to magento 2.0.7 .

In production mode also magento 2 as slow as in developer mode.

I have aslo enable cache and merge css and js.

Till speed is slow give me batter way to speed magento 2.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99155/after-installing-my-magento2-is-extremely-slow-though-i-did-not-install-sample

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- install php7
- install and enable opcache (make  opcache.enable = On, opcache.max_accelerated_files = 65535)
- disable xdebug (comment zend_extension). `php -i|grep xdebug` should not found xdebug settings
- run  `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
- run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`
- enable production mode in apache/nginx
- run `bin/magento cache:flush` (and verify that all caches enabled with  `bin/magento cache:status` )
- run `composer dump-autoload -o`
- run `chown -R www-data:www-date {magento_root}` (use user:group for your distro)
- install and configure varnish
- install and configure redis

You can find more details in [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com)

PS: if this not help, please install xhprof/tideways extension and post profile for category page