# Magento 2: how to improve response time when changing colors?

Tags: magento2, color-swatches

Currently it takes around 4-5 seconds to update the product images when you click on a color swatch in Magento 2. Example:

https://youtu.be/AeOTEth4TOc

How can you improve this performance?

It seems all the image information is already available in the `jsonConfig` object, so it shouldn't take this long even when you're in developer mode.

Comment: Can you try to do all steps described in http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125979/magento-2-speed-issues/126006#126006 and try one more time?

Comment: @KAndy how long does it take for you to change colors on /caesar-warm-up-pant.html in developer mode? (It would be better if I can increase the performance in developer mode since that's the mode I'm in when developing.)

Comment: For me it 0.3 sec. But it looks for me as a bug, so please create issue on github

Comment: @KAndy it was reported in [issue #5655](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5655).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to resolve the performance issues and now the product images update almost immediately even in developer mode, so hope the solution below will help others who found themselves in a similar situation. Example after fix:

https://youtu.be/MDpAy_iA3gw

To fix this, first I overrode `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/templates/product/view/renderer.phtml` by copying the file to `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Swatches/templates/product/view/renderer.phtml`.

Then replace the code in this file with this:

```
<?php /** @var $block \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable */ ?>
<div class="swatch-opt"></div>
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer'], function($) {
  var oJsonConfig = <?php echo $block->getJsonConfig(); ?>;

  $('.swatch-opt').SwatchRenderer({
    jsonConfig: oJsonConfig,
    jsonSwatchConfig: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $swatchOptions = $block->getJsonSwatchConfig(); ?>,
    mediaCallback: '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ //echo $block->getMediaCallback() ?>'
  });

  // Need to wait for gallery to be loaded before querying $('.fotorama')
  $('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]').on('gallery:loaded', function() {
    // NOTE: Using .one() instead of .on() to prevent duplicate bindings.
    $('.fotorama').one('fotorama:ready', function(e, fotorama, extra) {

      // Update product images faster when clicking on color swatch
      $('.swatch-option.color').click(function() {
        var sOptionId = this.getAttribute('option-id');
        for (var attributeId in oJsonConfig.attributes) {
          var oAttribute = oJsonConfig.attributes[attributeId];
          if (oAttribute.code==='color') {
            for (var i=0; i<oAttribute.options.length; ++i) {
              var oOption = oAttribute.options[i];
              if (oOption.id===sOptionId) {
                // Gather images
                var aImages = oJsonConfig.images[oOption.products[0]],
                  aFotoramaImages = [];
                for (var j=0; j<aImages.length; ++j) {
                  if (aImages[j].isMain) {
                    // Main image (first position)
                    aFotoramaImages[0] = {
                      full: aImages[j].full,
                      img: aImages[j].img,
                      thumb: aImages[j].thumb
                    };
                  } else {
                    // Subsequent images
                    aFotoramaImages[aImages[j].position] = {
                      full: aImages[j].full,
                      img: aImages[j].img,
                      thumb: aImages[j].thumb
                    };
                  }
                }
                // Load images into Fotorama
                // API reference: http://fotorama.io/customize/api/
                fotorama.load(aFotoramaImages);
                break;
              }
            }
            break;
          }
        }
      });

    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Hopefully my comments are sufficient to understand what's going on, but here are some notes that might not be obvious at first:

- I moved `jsonConfig` one scope up to the variable `oJsonConfig` in order to access it outside `.SwatchRenderer()`. This object contains all the image data we need to update the Fotorama plugin when the user selects a color swatch.
- The color swatch click handler needs to be attached using `.one()` instead of `.on()` to prevent adding the same event handler again whenever Fotorama is loaded with new images. I'm pretty sure you can also choose to move the click handler declaration outside of `fotorama:ready` and use `.on()` instead.
- The statement `echo $block->getMediaCallback()` was commented out since the default callback interferes with our new click handler.

Comment: Just to tell you that you solved my problem with your solution, though there is a small touchup needed `require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'swatchRenderer'],` should be replaced by `require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui', "Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer"],`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing that out. After upgrading from 2.0 to 2.1.1 `swatchRenderer` needs to be replaced with `Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer`. I'll update the solution.

Comment: @10basetom  If I use custom slider to display product images then how to replace swatches images ?

Comment: @RonakChauhan it will depend on the slider plugin. Most should have the ability to refresh or update the slides by passing in an object or array of images.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175627/change-images-as-per-swatches-using-custom-slider-on-product-detail-page check this question. I am using slick slider @10basetom

Comment: This would be amazing if there was an update for the Magento 2.4 branch. It's still so slow :(

Answer (score 1):

```
for magento 2.1.0

<div class="swatch-opt" data-role="swatch-options"></div>
<script>
    require(["jquery", "jquery/ui", "Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer"], function ($) {
        var oJsonConfig = <?php echo $block->getJsonConfig(); ?>;
        $('.swatch-opt').SwatchRenderer({                    
            jsonConfig: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonConfig(); ?>,
            jsonSwatchConfig: <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getJsonSwatchConfig(); ?>,
            mediaCallback: '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getMediaCallback() ?>'
        });
    $('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]').on('gallery:loaded', function() {
    // NOTE: Using .one() instead of .on() to prevent duplicate bindings.
    $('.fotorama').one('fotorama:ready', function(e, fotorama, extra) {
      // Update product images faster when clicking on color swatch
      $('.swatch-option.color').click(function() {        
        var sOptionId = this.getAttribute('option-id');
        for (var attributeId in oJsonConfig.attributes) {
          console.log(oJsonConfig);
          var oAttribute = oJsonConfig.attributes[attributeId];
          if (oAttribute.code==='color') {
            for (var i=0; i<oAttribute.options.length; ++i) {
              var oOption = oAttribute.options[i];
              if (oOption.id===sOptionId) {
                // Gather images
                var aImages = oJsonConfig.images[oOption.products[0]],
                  aFotoramaImages = [];
                for (var j=0; j<aImages.length; ++j) {
                  if (aImages[j].isMain) {
                    // Main image (first position)
                    aFotoramaImages[0] = {
                      full: aImages[j].full,
                      img: aImages[j].img,
                      thumb: aImages[j].thumb
                    };
                  } else {
                    // Subsequent images
                    aFotoramaImages[aImages[j].position] = {
                      full: aImages[j].full,
                      img: aImages[j].img,
                      thumb: aImages[j].thumb
                    };
                  }
                }
                // Load images into Fotorama
                // API reference: http://fotorama.io/customize/api/
                fotorama.load(aFotoramaImages);
                break;
              }
            }
            break;
          }
        }
      });

    });
  });
});
</script>
```