# Change images as per Swatches using Custom Slider on Product Detail page

Tags: configurable-product, swatches, magento2.1.6, slider, gallery

I have created Custom Slick slider to display product images on Product detail page.
[image]

But I want to change images as per change on color Swatches.

[image]

> > Note : I'm using `getGalleryImagesJson()` to retrieve image data.

**So I want to change images as per swatches which works on `fotorama` (default slider).**

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For reloading Gallery images information you need to generate backend code - new images and frontend code - javascript code.
For generating images you can create plugin like this:

```
 <type name="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable">
        <plugin name="Amasty_Conf::configurable" type="Amasty\Conf\Plugin\Product\Renderer\Configurable"/>
 </type>
```

where in function

```
 public function afterGetJsonConfig(
    TypeConfigurable $subject,
    $result
) {
    if ($result &&
        $subject->getNameInLayout() == 'product.info.options.swatches'
    ) {
        $config = $this->jsonDecoder->decode($result);
        $block = $this->blockFactory->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery', 'product.view.gallery');
        $block->setProduct($subject->getProduct());
        $config['gallery_images'] = $block->getGalleryImagesJson();

        $result = $this->jsonEncoder->encode($config);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Will add information what you need.

After we need to create Javascript file. 
For example, you can override Magento js file:

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer' : 'Amasty_Conf/js/swatch-renderer',
```

And finally add your custom code to change images:

```
  _EventListener: function () {           
        var $widget = this;

        $widget.element.on('click', '.' + this.options.classes.optionClass, function () {
            return $widget._AmOnClick($(this), $widget);
        });
```

Where in _AmOnClick you need to reload your custom gallery and run Slick initialize code.